# How to configure Ubuntu server to accept only LAN connection through SSH?

Tags: server, ssh, ethernet, lan

I have ubuntu-16.04.1-server connected to my router through Ethernet.
I only want local PCs to be able to connect to it using SSH.
How to do that?

also (if possible),
How to disconnect this server from the Internet (completely) and only accept LAN SSH requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your router is configured to forward traffic to your server, it should be inaccessible from outside your LAN already.

However for an extra layer of security, you can configure the default firewall to only accept LAN connections by specifying an appropriate IP range, either via `iptables` or via `ufw` e.g.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to connect to my server from my friend's house and couldn't get access.